# Can't figure out how to get rid of a graphic when I figure hit a button

Tags: java, graphics, paintcomponent, shapes

I'm trying to make it so when you push a button, you destroy something, but I can't get the enemy to disappear(red square)  Here's the code for the graphics:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            Ellipse2D P1 = (new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, 40, 40));
            Rectangle2D P2 = (new Rectangle2D.Double(x2, y2, 40, 40));
            g2.fill(P1);
            g2.setPaint(Color.RED);
            g2.fill(P2);
        }
```

How would I get the Rectangle2D to disappear using this method of key bindings?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            repaint();
            x += velx;
            y += vely;
            x2 += velx2;
            y2 += vely2;
        }
        public void up() {
            vely = -2;
            velx = 0;       
        }
        public void down() {
            vely = 2;
            velx = 0;       
        }
        public void left() {
            vely = 0;
            velx = -2;      
        }
        public void right() {
            vely = 0;
            velx = 2;       
        }
        public void stop() {
            vely = 0;
            velx = 0;       
        }
        public void stop2() {
            vely2 = 0;
            velx2 = 0;      
        }
        public void up2() {
            vely2 = -2;
            velx2 = 0;      
        }
        public void down2() {
            vely2 = 2;
            velx2 = 0;      
        }
        public void left2() {
            vely2 = 0;
            velx2 = -2;     
        }
        public void right2() {
            vely2 = 0;
            velx2 = 2;      
        }
        public void attack() {
            if (x <= x2+100 && y <= y2+100){

            }
        }
        //public void attack() {
        //  
        //}
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            int code = e.getKeyCode();
            if(code == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
                up();
            }
            if(code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
                down();
            }
            if(code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
                left();
            }
            if(code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
                right();
            }
            if(code == KeyEvent.VK_W){
                up2();
            }
            if(code == KeyEvent.VK_S){
                down2();
            }
            if(code == KeyEvent.VK_A){
                left2();
            }
            if(code == KeyEvent.VK_D){
                right2();
            }
            if(code == KeyEvent.VK_P){
                stop();
            }
            if(code == KeyEvent.VK_O){
                stop2();
            }
            if(code == KeyEvent.VK_Z){
                attack();
            }

        }
```

Comment: Just don't draw the rectangle? Consider keeping a collection of game objects that are drawn polymorphically and just iterate through the collection to draw them. Then removing/adding new objects will ensure they're drawn.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating the objects to be painted within the `paintComponent` method itself, maintain a collection of objects that are to be rendered and loop through that collection each `paintComponent` call. Then "destroying" the P2 object is done by simply removing from the collection.